# Basic Mouse Click Code - Need Fix

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm attempting to write a code where depending on where you click on the screen either a ball or square is made ("square" and "circle" are defined earlier):

```
def squareball(x,y):
    if x <0:
        square
    if x >=0:
        circle
canvas.onclick(squareball,2)
```

However when I click the middle mouse button nothing happens.

Comment: You don't seem to be calling either square or circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visit your old functions, `square` and `circle`.
If they are something like:
`def <func_name>:`, insert parentheses, making it `def <func_name>():`

After doing or not doing that, make `square` to `square()` and `circle` to `circle()` in the `if/else` statement.

Summary: You are not calling your functions.

Comment: I'm getting this error-  TypeError: square() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'x' and 'y'

Comment: 1. You have defined `squareball` with 2 arguments but seem to be not calling it. However, you are not using `y` inside the function, remove it from the arguments.

2. Call the functions as `func(x)`. Literally.